# I tried running this code but it throws Error in match.fun(FUN) : argument "FUN" is missing, with no default when i run

Tags: r, data-analysis, quantitative-finance

whenever i run this line of code it throws an error:Error in match.fun(FUN) : argument "FUN" is missing, with no default

```
## calculating Indicator columns for each ticker
df = pblapply(as.list(unique(df$tickers)))
## rowbind data
df = rbindlist(df,use.names = TRUE))
```

Previous code to this error

```
require("BatchGetSymbols");require("quantmod");require("pbapply")
require("data.table")
## tickers
tickers = c("^NSEI","^NSEMDCP50","^NSEMDCP50","NIFTYSMLCAP50.NS","^CNX100")

## download data
data = BatchGetSymbols(tickers=tickers,first.date = "2000-01-01",last.date = Sys.Date(),
                       thresh.bad.data = 0.50, bench.ticker = "^GSPC",
                       type.return = "arit",freq.data = "daily",how.to.aggregate = "last",
                       do.complete.data = TRUE,do.fill.missing.prices = TRUE)
## output ticker summary
data$df.control

## extract price data
df = as.data.frame(data$df.tickers)

# adjust column names for TTR handling
names(df)[9:10] <- c("Returns_price_adjusted","Returns_closing_adjusted")
```

Comment: Welcome to [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/) @Brownnboi. Can you please share some sample data to test and validate and also specify at what step you are getting the error?

Comment: @isa ive added the previous code

Comment: You haven't specified any function argument inside this code `df = pblapply(as.list(unique(df$tickers)))`. Try this `df = pblapply(as.list(df$tickers), unique)` this should work.

Comment: What function do you want to apply to the unique values of df$tickers?? ie `pblapply(df$tickers, the_function_you want)`

Comment: @isa i tried but after that but when i return df it shows no value

Comment: Try this `df <- pblapply(list(mtcars$mpg), unique)` @Brownnboi, you will get some output. Don't know why it isn't working for you. Can you also check what values does `df$tickers` has.